# Seam: How to get session-ID from Servlet-Request

Tags: servlets, seam, seam2

I have a big Seam project and want to serve some XML or binary data without any JSF actions or interference.

So I decided to use servlets. The method I used is described here:
http://www.seamframework.org/Documentation/ReplacingServletsWithSeamResources

Actually, I'm working with two servlets providing different information.

What I want to implement now is that I can track every session using the session-id.
But: Everytime the servlet is called, I get a new session-id.

In one forum they write that I have to implement a session-tracker (https://community.jboss.org/thread/190326). 
That means:

a) after the first call I have to send the session-id back to the client

b) after that, at every call the client has to send the session-id to the server.

c) Now the server can get the session from the session tracker.

Is there no easier solution? I mean, there should be any possibility that the Seam-servlet detects automatically that the call came from the same client as before.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these requests coming from a modern web browser, or some standalone client? Is the JSESSIONID cookie being reused on subsequent requests?

If you think the cookie *should* be there, you can use HttpServletReqeust.getCookies() to see if the server is seeing it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies()